# PHP array into a CSV file

Tags: php, arrays, csv

my problem is, that I want to save an array into a CSV file.
Here my code:

```
//Webseite auslesen
$string = file_get_contents("***Zensiert***");    
$helper = preg_match_all('!<a.*?href=\"([^\"]*)\"[^>]*>(.*?)</a>!', $string, $matches);    
$fl_array = preg_grep('/^http.*/', $matches[1]);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($fl_array);
echo '</pre>';

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'a');

foreach ($fl_array as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```

The file is generated, but without content?!
I didn't see the mistake...

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Attempt with the `w+` permission on `fopen()`, secondly, what are the actual contents of `$fl_array`? I believe as `a` will place the file pointer at the ***end*** of the file. See docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change some lines to those

```
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($df, array_keys(reset($fl_array))); //Put column names as the 1st row (you may comment this line)
foreach ($fl_array as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp);
```

This opens file to write.

And in your code you probably want to change that foreach into:  `fputcsv($fp, $fl_array );`

Answer (score 0):

```
fputcsv($fp, $fields);
```

$fields isn't an array.. so that was the problem.